# The relationship could not be changed because one or more properties of the foreigner keys are not nullable

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a main table and a child table. I would like to create a new row in the main table and related a row in the child table with this new row. The actual row in the child row has all the foreginer keys.

So I am trying this code:

```
MyTypeA myNewParent = new Parent();
myNewParent.Childs.Add(myChild);
myChild.MyParent = myNewType;
myOldParent.Childs.Remove(miChild);
```

But I get the error that the relationship can't be changed because the foreigner key is not nullable. In the database the FK does not allow null values, this is true.

But when I  create a new parent and a new child, I can do:

```
myTypeA myParent = new myTypeA();
myTypeB myChild = new myTypeB();
myParent.Childs.A(myChild);
```

And it works fine.

How can I change the parent of my child?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow change tracking to do relationship fixup, inside the same `DbContext` scope, do the following:

- read the new parent and the child form the Db
- add the child to the new parent. This will fix up the relationship (change the FK)
- call `.SaveChanges()`

If your objects are coming from an external service, you need to attach them to a new `DbContext`, and do the same as if you had recovered them from the database. Onse the entties are inside a "live" `DbContext`, change tracking takes care of relationships.

Comment: Create a DbContext, Add the parent to it, with `.Add()`. Attach the child to the context, with `.Attach()`, and them add the child to the parents collection. Do `.SaveChanges()`. This should work. If not, let me know.

Comment: So if I am not wrong, you mean I need a second dbContext to send to added the new parent to the database, with an extra saveChanges and later change the relationship?

Comment: If you showed your code, I could give you more exact advice. That code it's only in your PC and your head. Show it to me, and I'll give you an exact explanation. It only has to do with the correcet entity states before you make the relationship and call .SaveChanges()